# How to add wrap future builder inside column

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is my simple outline code to generate ListView inside Future builder.

What I wanted to achieve is that I want some widget below of the  FutureBuilder widget so I wrapped it with column but the content of future builder got just vanished after adding, but before adding it was fine.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  child:FutureBuilder(
      future: msDB.getListOfMoviesSeries(widget.type,widget.isWatched),
    builder: (BuildContextcontext, AsyncSnapshot<List<MovieSeries>> snapshot) {
        return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
        ........
    )
        }
    );
  }
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you add shrinkWrap:true in your ListView builder and try it again?

Comment: @shubham yes it worked thanks. Can you explain a bit what was wrong ?

Comment: Sure I will post it as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using ListView in Column, The Column has an unbounded height in the vertical axis and your ListView will try to expand to maxHeight and the flutter framework will throw an error. By setting shrinkWrap to true, the extent of the scroll view in the scroll direction is determined by the contents being viewed

So to fix the issue you add following line in your ListView.builder

```
shrinkWrap:true
```

You can read more about [shrinkWrap here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/shrinkWrap.html)

Hope this helps!